# "I can't see (where the car is parked)." What kind of clause is that one?

Tags: clauses

I was reading a grammar book and I came across a practice where you are asked to locate the adjectival clause in a sentence.

> I can't see where the car is parked.

was one of the items.

However, I can't see how "where the car is parked" can be an adjectival clause.
From my understanding, it is a noun clause.

So, is "where the car is parked" a noun clause or an adjectival clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would agree. The clause "where the car is parked" functions as a noun and object of the verb "can't see".  Such clauses can be used as modfiers:

> I can't see the place where the car is parked.

But that is not the case in the example you gave.

If this was a test question, I'd answer with "where the car is parked", since that almost certainly the response that gets the marks.  But I'd sigh while doing it.

It is possible that you have misread the question.  It could say "locate the adjective clause, if one exists" or similar. In which case it might be a deliberate case of a sentence that seems to have an adjective clause, but doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for putting my mind at ease. Unfortunately, the practice specifically asks to locate/identify the adjectival clause in each given sentence. It seems like that sentence belonged in the "Noun Clauses" chapter and appeared in the "Adjectival Clauses" chapter my mistake.